# Override Custom Page Template with page.php, and then calling Custom page template with get_template_part()

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I want to use page.php for ALL pages (so I don't have to repeat forexample get_header() and #section-top in all page templates) and then use get_template_part() to call content based on page-template. Right now I have my page.php and two content-parts, one is set to be standard, 'content-flexible.php' (if no Page Template is set) and the other is used to show posts 'content-posts.php'.

This is my page.php file:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main id="page-main" role="main" class="main">
        <?php 

        ?>
    <section id="section-top" class="header cf">        
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    </section>
    <div id="content-wrap" class="wrap cf">
            <div id="inner-content" class="wrap cf">
            <?php 
                //Use page-templates for content
                if( $post->post_parent !== 0 ) {
                    get_template_part('page-parts/content', 'posts');
                } else {
                get_template_part('page-parts/content', 'flexible');
                }
            ?>
            </div>  <!-- /inner-content -->
    </div> <!-- end /content-wrap -->   
</main>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Right now the else statement works (content-flixible.php is called), however when I set Page Template to "Posts page" it uses only the content-posts.php, since it follows WordPress normal hierarchy. How can I override this so I always use 'page.php' only swapping the content based on which Page Template is used in admin-pages?